# Installed app is crashing everytime on launching

Tags: ios, iphone, crash, sandbox

I have installed my app last week on device. I used it for 2 days and after that I haven't used it for 3-4 days. Now I am trying to launch but it is not launching and crashing immediately.

I found logs as follows:

> Feb  1 17:17:53 M_iPhone amfid[183]  :
>   /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/CB42BC38-71E7-4BA5-AD99-3703C2153DAF/test.app/test
>   not valid: 0xe8008018: The identity used to sign the executable is no
>   longer valid. Feb  1 17:17:53 M-iPhone kernel[0]  : AMFI:
>   hook..execve() killing pid 984: no code signature Feb  1 17:17:53
>   M-iPhone kernel[0]  : Sandbox: hook..execve() killing pid 984:
>   application requires container but none set Feb  1 17:17:53 M-iPhone
>   com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.test.test[0xb771][984])
>   : Service exited due to signal: Killed: 9

When I uninstalled and reinstall app then it is working fine.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Probably the builds that get uploaded to the device are signed for limited time (maybe 1-2 days), that is why after reinstall and signing again, everything works again.

Comment: how to check the builds are signed for limited time? and how to change this time?

Comment: As your crash log clearly says, signing identity to sign your app was invalid, and that's why your app was not launched. This happens when you revoke the developer certificate used to sign the app. Maybe, you have revoked the developer certificate and created new one?

Comment: No, I have not revoked the developer certificate but now when I check keychain, its saying developer certificate is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to remove and re-add your apple id, it works for me for months.

xcode: Preferences...
Accounts
Select your apple account
Remove that (-)
Add again your apple account (+)
Re install your app!